# Como agregar diferentes objetos a mongodb?

Tags: nodejs, api, mongodb, mongoose

Trabajo con nodejs, y descargo info de un api, todo bien hasta ahi pero a la hora de querer guardar esa informacion en mongo, me lo guarda como un solo objeto, lo que yo quisiera saber es como guardar objeto por objeto

la data que me regresa el api es algo asi

```
"data" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "bD5",
            "tractor" : "037",
            "SerialNumber" : "xxxxxx"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "b4D",
            "tractor" : "041",
            "SerialNumber" : "xxxxxxx"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "b50",
            "tractor" : "054",
            "SerialNumber" : "xxxxxx"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "b28",
            "tractor" : "065",
            "SerialNumber" : "xxxxxxx"
        }, 
        {
            "id" : "bAC",
            "tractor" : "112",
            "SerialNumber" : "xxxxxxxx"
        }, 
]
```

y esto me lo guarda como un solo objeto

con el codigo que lo guardo es este

```
async function getAllTruck(req, res) {

    let data = []
    //let results = []
    await api.call('Get', {
        typeName: 'Device',
        search: {
            name: data.userName
        }
    }, async function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err)
            return
        }
        let results = []

        for await (let element of data) {
            console.log(element.groups)
            results.push({ id: element.id, tractor: element.name, SerialNumber: element.serialNumber })
        }

        Locales.findOneAndUpdate({}, { data: results }, { new: true, upsert: true }, (err, doc) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(500).send({ message: `Error al actualizar tractores locales: ${err}` });
            }
        });

        res.status(200).send({ data: results });
    })
}
```

y el modelo con el que lo uso es un simple arreglo

```
'use strict'

const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { DateTime } = require('mssql');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Tractor_local = new Schema({
    data: [{}]
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('TractorLocal', Tractor_local)
```

no tengo problema pero para hacer la consulta en lugar de usar un find, tengo que hacer un aggregate y es mucho mas problema

Comment: ¿Y porqué tu esquema sólo tiene una lista? ¿Los valores que recibes son siempre diferentes o se pueden repetir? Si se repiten ¿cuál sería el discriminador para diferenciarlos? Falta información sobre el propósito de dicha data para poder orientarte en cómo almacenarlos individualmente para que los documentos sean consistentes y no tengas duplicidad de datos. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tu schema deberia quedar asi:

```
const Tractor_local = new Schema({
    "id" : String,
    "tractor" : String,
    "SerialNumber" : String`
})
```

Y para guardarlos debes de crear una promesa por registro asi:

```
let promesasPendientes = []


results.forEach(data=>{
     //Se crea una promesa por cada elemento que se quiere guardar. 
     let promesa= Locales.findOneAndUpdate(
            //Comprobamos si ese documento existe en base al "id" definido en el schema
            { id: results.id },
            //Remplazamos todo el contenido 
            {  $set { ...results }}, 
            //Muy importante .exec(), que te devuelve la promesa sin resolverla. 
            { new: true, upsert: true }).exec()
     //Almacenamos esa promesa pendiente para que todas juntas se resuelvan
     promesasPendientes.push(promesa)
    
})


    Promise.all(promesasPendientes)
    //Mandas los datos resultantes dentro del then
    .then(resultados=> res.send({data:resultados}))
    //De esta manera puedes capturar cualquier error. Esta lógica
    // la puedes cambiar a lo que te convenga 
    .catch(error=> res.send(error))
```

Comment: El esquema que propones no tiene un campo `data`, luego en tu método `findOneAndUpdate` (que sólo actualiza 1 documento) le dices que actualice el primero que consiga, y coloque en un campo llamado `data` la lista de resultados, ¡esto lo haces para cada elemento de la lista!. La verdad que no termino de entender nada de la propuesta de solución que planteas. Asumo que `Locales` es el modelo construido a partir del esquema `Tractor_local`. Hace falta información en la pregunta para poder dar una respuesta satisfactoria, te sugiero que revises tu respuesta. Saludos

Comment: He editado la respuesta y agregue el parámetro de búsqueda. Tambien, elimino el campo data, que no es necesario segun la informacion que plantea la pregunta. Me parece bastante clara la pregunta como para responderla. En general, requiere cada resultado en un documento.

Comment: Y ciertamente `Locales` es como Christian Gtz designó la variable del esquema sugerido.

Comment: Si, realmente era el modelo que habia puesto y la respuesta de Legna, me quedo super facil, ahora si me muestra los datos separados por objetos y los querys ahora son mas sencillos